# Import a txt weighted adjacency list into a matrix

Tags: matlab, graph

I want to create a weighted adj matrix. Is there a good way that will work even with a huge data set?
I have this abc.txt file for example:

```
abc.txt
1 2 50
2 3 70
3 1 42
1 3 36
```

result should be

```
matrix=
0  50  36
0   0   70
42  0   0
```

How can I construct a weighted adjacency matrix from input dataset graph file as shown above that will contain the weights?

So basically input file has 3 columns  and the third column is the weights of each edge.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is a sparse definition of a matrix, using `sparse` is the simplest way to create it. If your matrix is thin (many zeros) you may also stick with the sparse matrix because it requires less memory. Then delete the last line.

```
S=load('abc.txt')
M=sparse(S(:,1),S(:,2),S(:,3))
M=full(M)
```

Comment: You probably mean `M=load('abc.txt'):`

Answer (score 1):

You could also apply [`spconvert`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spconvert.html) to the output of [`importdata`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html):

```
matrix = full(spconvert(importdata('abc.txt')));
```

Comment: thanx Daniel and Luis . i was looking exactly for luis 1 line code :) thanx alot